# Retrieve values based on keys from map inside maps

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, struts2, arraylist

I working on a project where I have to connect the specific database based on the bank_name.I am using java,struts2,hibernate.
for example:

```
{'sbi': 
   {'host':'111.111.15.45','port':3306,'username':'xxxx','password':'xxxx','database':'sbidb'}
```

Here **sbi** is a bank_name which is a **key**,then as a value there is another map. so I want to retrieve all values such as host,port,db based on bank_name(ex: 'sbi').
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple.

You Map is something like this:

```
 Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
 .....
```

Now you can retrieve the key value pair from inner map as below:

```
  Map<String,String> sbiMap = map.get("sbi");
  Set<String> keys = sbiMap.keySet();
  for(String key: keys){
    System.out.println("key="+key+" value = " + sbiMap.get(key));
  }
```

This will print all inner keys and corresponding values in the map for `sbi`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`. To get the keys for the interior map use the `keySet()` function of the map. Ex:

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> X;
Set<String> sbikeys = X.get('sbi').keySet();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following data structure to achieve this

```
Map<String, Map<String,String> bankdetails =  new HashMap<String, Map<String,String> ();
```

to put details of sbi,

first populate sbi specific details

```
HashMap<String, String> details =  new HashMap<String,String>();

   details.put("host","XXXX);

   details.put("port", "101111");

  ......
```

then use to put details of sbi as below

```
bankdetails.put(sbi ,details);
```

Comment: if there is more than 10 banks and all there details are different then what should be done?

Comment: I mean, bankdetails.put(sbi ,details); and if I want to put another deatils such as details.put("host","yyyy") for another bank, then i should create another map like details.